# Time Series with gaps in the dependent variable

Tags: time-series

I have a time series data with a dependent variable representing a stock market value of some stock. This data is available for weekdays, but unavailable for weekends as there is no trade. In addition I have values of some independent variables. This data includes weekends in addition to weekdays.
What should I do in this situation ?

Erasing the rows with missing weekend data will cause for data loss of the independent variables.
Filling the gaps with the last observation (last observation carried forward?) ?
Filling the gaps with some sort of average ?

Comment: Interpolation (using any method) is almost certainly the wrong solution. Simply ignoring those dates may be fine, depending on your end goal (which you haven't mentioned).